# How to avoid selecting a day in the calendar in shiny R based on the dateRangeInput

Tags: r, date, shiny

Is there a way that you do not have to select a day in the calendar using the dateRangeInput in SHiny if your format is "yyyy-mm" ? I'm new to R and shiny. Thanks for looking into this.

Here is my code:

```
 library(shiny)

 ui <-fluidPage(
   dateRangeInput("reportdate", 
             "Report Date",
              format = "yyyy-mm",
              startview = 'year',
              start = "2001-01",
              end   = "2020-12",
              min = "2001-01",
              max = "2020-12"
              )
 )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

 output$report <- renderPrint({
    print(input$reportdate)
 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't think so, the help page says "start and end are always specified in yyyy-mm-dd, even if the display format is different". So all format is doing is adjusting the displayed values, not the actual values

Comment: Hi Nate Day - Thank you for your time. I'm just trying for the user to select the Month and Year without showing the Day Calendar for that period. I just thought there is a way for the user not to select any day in the calendar if the Month and Year is the only selection in the dateRangeInput.

Comment: yea it seems like there would be that option, but I couldn't find a way to do it and the help made me believe the options were really just superficial appearance. Even the JS help page for this doesn't look like there is that optionality Maybe you just ditch the date selector inputs and use drop down menus instead?

Comment: Thank you for your time in looking into this. Appreciate it and you have a great day!